# 5V or 12V ARM board with USB3 host + USB3 OTG?

Tags: usb

I need to find an ARM development board that can be powered with a 5V or 12V PSU. It also must have USB 3 host and USB 3 OTG. It should also have a MicroSD slot and more RAM is a good thing, but I will be happy with 1GB.

Other than that, it should be as small as possible, but that's not very important for a prototype. Something similar to the ODROID-XU3 Lite would be great for a prototype, but it's gone out of production and newer versions doesn't have USB3 OTG. http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G141351880955